# Asynchronous data copy between User space and Kernel space in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to copy data between kernel space and user space, and do it asynchronously by other threads.

I have done it by using ***workqueue***+***get_user_pages***+***kmap***,
(workqueue for kernel thread, get_user_pages for pinning user pages, kmap for mapping user pages to kernel)
and it works.

I wonder if there is better way to do it with lower code overhead.

Thanks!

PS:I use memcpy to copy data, is there another better function to copy?